# Delete lines beginning with #

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, awk, perl

How do I delete lines beginning with a `#`, given that there can be whitespace on the left and right of the `#`?

```
  # Master socket provides access to userdb information. It's typically
```

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work, but I've not given deep thought to it:

```
sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/d'
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `grep` for that

```
grep -vh '^[[:space:]]*#' filename
```

Since, as I presume, you are stripping comments from some file, you might also consider removing empty lines, which expands the above to:

```
grep -vh '^[[:space:]]*\(#\|$\)' filename
```

Answer (score 3):

`awk` solution is to invert matching your pattern.

```
$> cat ./text
elephant
# Master socket provides access to userdb information. It's typically
zoo
 #ok
penguin
# !

$> awk '!/^(\ )*#/ {print $0}' ./text
elephant
zoo
penguin
```

Comment: No need to escape the space character, no need to capture the space character, no need to specify the default action: `awk '!/^ *#/' ./text`.

Comment: `awk '/^ *#/{next}1' file` should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -ne 'print if ! /^\s*#/' ./text
```

Comment: hi @Peter-john-acklam, would this work when the code is followed by # comment?

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data posted by ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ...

```
$ grep -vPh '^\s*#' filename.txt | grep -Po '\w+'
elephant
zoo
penguin
```

I prefer using pcre with grep so I use the -P switch for grep (must be GNU grep). The second grep is pure sugar to give you the words with no white-space. It would also "remove" empty lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ perl -pi -e '$_="" if /^\s*#/' filename
```

Comment: That's not good - doesn't delete lines, and clears lines like `a#b`